# SwiftyDropbox list folders only

Tags: swift, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

Im using `SwiftyDropbox` SDK in my iOS application, im trying to list folders only in my app then user can choose a folder (not a file).

in `ViewController` =>  `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let dropboxClient = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient else{
        return
    }

    let listFolders = dropboxClient.files.listFolder(path: "")
    listFolders.response{ response, error in
        guard let result = response else{
            return
        }

        for entry in result.entries{
            print(entry)
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

entry is >

```
  { 
      id = "id:0GMPvYwuVEAAAAAAAAAABw";
      name = "Folder A";
      "path_display" = "/Folder A";
      "path_lower" = "/folder a";
  }
```

how can i find this entry is folder and it contains sub folder or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast each `entry` inside of your `result.entries` `for` loop like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let dropboxClient = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient else{
        return
    }

    for entry in result.entries{
       guard let file = entry as? Files.FolderMetadata else{
         return
       }

       // only folders
       print(entry)

       // *********  or 
       gurad let entry is Files.FolderMetadata else{
         return
       }

       // only folders
       print(entry)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching for this. But it should be `guard entry is Files.FolderMetadata else { return }`, without `let`, should be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to list folders only (though we'll consider it a feature request), so you'll need to list everything and filter out files.

You can distinguish between `FileMetadata`, `FolderMetadata`, and `DeletedMetadata` by `switch`ing on the `Metadata` object as [shown in the README](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#response-handling-edge-cases).

If you need subfolders as well, you can specify `recursive=true` when calling [`listFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes10listFolderFT4pathSS9recursiveSb16includeMediaInfoSb14includeDeletedSb31includeHasExplicitSharedMembersSb_GCS_10RpcRequestCCS_5Files26ListFolderResultSerializerCS2_25ListFolderErrorSerializer_).